# Serialization into static data using Boost and IOStreams

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, arrays

I'm trying to take a complex, nested structure and store it directly in a .cpp file as static data. The approach I'd like to take is to take my object (which already supports Boost serialization) and serialize it as a binary archive *into a byte array*. I could then take that byte array, and walk through it to autogenerate the required .cpp code to hold the binary array. Then, I'd like to deserialize from that byte array *back into the object*.

So basically, at the end of the day I'd like something like this:

```
unsigned char* my_obj = { 10, 48, 48, 30, 20 ... }
```

When I want to use that data, I'd just wrap it in the "byte stream" and pass it into Boost again to deserialize back into my actual object.

My question is: is there some easy way to pass byte arrays around as streams? Boost deals with istreams and ostreams for reading and writing the archives. I don't want to use a stringstream or a filestream, but rather what I suppose may be a custom stream that just acts as a giant byte array for whatever is passed to it.

I feel like there should be a great way to create this custom stream and have it seamlessly work with the Boost serialization... I'm just not really sure where to begin?

Comment: Still sounds like you are after a ostringstream

Comment: Oh yeah? I assumed it wasn't the tool for the job because I didn't really want a string, but maybe you're right! I'll try something out to see if that works...

Comment: Well I am not sure it's the "ideal" tool, but if you want to store the data into a tempory stream that the best I can think of. Or if you can just make string from the tokenised code that would be easy as well.

Comment: If your concern is that `std::ostringstream` will make a copy of the data (and it definitely will), then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13059195/636019) has you covered. (Just make sure to open the stream in binary mode.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> unsigned char* my_obj = { 10, 48, 48, 30, 20 ... }

It is better to use:

```
unsigned char my_obj[] = { 10, 48, 48, 30, 20 ... }
```

So you will have array, which knows it's size, not just pointer to begin. Also, add const if you don't plan to modify it.

---

> My question is: is there some easy way to pass byte arrays around as streams? Boost deals with istreams and ostreams for reading and writing the archives. I don't want to use a stringstream or a filestream, but rather what I suppose may be a custom stream that just acts as a giant byte array for whatever is passed to it.

Check [Boost's array_source and array_sink](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/array.html).

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc2968a74cf19f7b):

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    double value;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int)
    {
        ar & value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Data d={3.1415926};
    char buffer[256];
    {
        iostreams::array_sink sink(buffer);
        iostreams::stream<iostreams::array_sink> stream(sink);
        archive::binary_oarchive out_archive(stream);
        out_archive << d;
    }
    Data restored = {0.0};
    {
        iostreams::array_source source(buffer);
        iostreams::stream<iostreams::array_source> stream(source);
        archive::binary_iarchive in_archive(stream);
        in_archive >> restored;
    }
    cout << boolalpha << ( restored.value == d.value ) << endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
true
```

Comment: This definitely put me on the right track. I ended up using a very similar technique shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015582/direct-boost-serialization-to-char-array/5604782#comment18123762_5604782

In that approach, I didn't need to know the buffer size beforehand, and that's what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This leaves out a very important case: when the array of bytes you want to store is a member of a class. If you do not a priori know the size of the array of bytes, then you use a unsigned char* member which is allocated in the constructor. However boost cannot serialize pointers to primitive types, it isn't supported (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076299/how-do-i-serialize-a-class-containing-pointers-to-primitives/19077087#19077087). std::string could work, if it weren't for the fact that 0x0 (which is perfectly valid for binary data) in a char* is interpreted as the null terminator.

Comment: If you need to serialize an array of bytes that is also a class member, try a std::vector<unsigned char>.