# boost serialization of pointer to primitive without wrapper

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Is there any way to serialize a pointer to a primitive without wrapping it in a class?

I notice a comment on the following question that it would require tracking all primitives of that type in the program, which I guess could slow down serialization somewhat.  But what if I'm ok with that?  Is there a way to enable tracking for all primitive types?

[How do I serialize a class containing pointers to primitives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076299/how-do-i-serialize-a-class-containing-pointers-to-primitives)

I found this thread (from 2006) which also alludes to the problem.  It seems that serializing a pointer to primitive should be possible, but the lack of tracking makes it something that you probably would not want. It seems to allude to the possibility but does not explain if it was ever implemented.

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/serialization-serialization-of-pointers-to-primitive-types-td2561086.html

Comment: Just wrap it in a class... It's the sane thing to do. What's against that?

Comment: It's kind of a complicated scenario.  But it has to do with creating a DSL that uses snippets of C++ code.  I would like the users of the DSL to be able to use the C++ types they are used to.

Comment: I don't see how the DSL is related (unless I have the picture upside down and you are (ab)using serialization for parsing the DSL). I assume something like Proto-based eDSL (Expression Templates)? In that case, nothing prevents you from just transforming the ast. Or, as I'd prefer, writing serialization with Boost Spirit Karma and side step the whole "issue"

Comment: It's a good point, I could translate the types while generating the code.  For now I am trying to avoid doing much parsing of the C++ code and for the most part just pass the snippets through without modification.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a overload function for `operator&`,like this:

```
template<class Archive>
void operator&(Archive & ar, const char* &p)
{

}
```