# XML serialization with boost (left of '.serialize' must have class/struct/union)

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have the two classes BaseTolerance and ImageProcessingTask. I get the error Message: 'error C2228: left of '.serialize' must have class/struct/union'.

If the line (in ImageProcessingTask)

```
        ar & make_nvp("ToleranceToMeasure", tolerance_to_measure_);
```

is commented out, the error message disappears.

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

class BaseTolerance
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
    ar & make_nvp("ToleranceName", tolerance_name_);
}

    char* tolerance_name_;
    public:
    BaseTolerance();
    ~BaseTolerance();

    char* GetToleranceName();
    void SetToleranceName(char* name);
};
```

and

```
#include "GeometricTolerance.h"

class ImageProcessingTask
{
    BaseTolerance *tolerance_to_measure_;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        using boost::serialization::make_nvp;               
        ar & make_nvp("ToleranceToMeasure", tolerance_to_measure_);
    }
public:
    ImageProcessingTask();
    ~ImageProcessingTask();

    BaseTolerance *GetToleranceToMeasure();
    void SetToleranceToMeasure(BaseTolerance *tolerance);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error actually came from trying to serialize char*, once i saw that, i switched to std::string, as proposed in [Direct boost serialization to char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015582/direct-boost-serialization-to-char-array)